# Alterar status de usuário logado

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou aprendendo PHP e criei um sistema de login. Gostaria de ajuda com o código para alterar o status do usuário logado.

Eu tenho uma lista com usuários que estão online e, ao rodar esse script, queria alterar o status do usuário que já tiver passado mais de 50 minutos com status online, só que ele está alterando o status de todos os usuários.

Esse é meu código:

```php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=pdo","root","");

$view = $pdo->prepare("SELECT agora,lastaccesso FROM users");
$view->execute();

foreach ($view as $mostra):
    $lastaccesso = $mostra['lastaccesso']; 
    $agora = $mostra['agora']; 
    $horaNova = strtotime("$lastaccesso + 5 minutes");
    $horaNovaFormatada = date("H:i", $horaNova);
    if ($horaNovaFormatada  < $agora):
        $altera = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET online='" . $sim_nao . "'");
        $altera->execute();
        if($altera):
            echo "<script>window.location = 'online.php'</script>";
        else:
            echo "erro";
        endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: voce está setando essa variavel $sim_nao em algum lugar?

Comment: Aparentemente você não está fechando o primeiro `if`

Comment: eu havia esquecido da variavel e do if , ja coloquei e o resultado é o mesmo . ele altera status de todos  os usuarios , mas eu so quero que seja aterado dos usuarios que estao a mais de 1 hora com status online

Comment: tentei esse codigo mas esta me retornando erro .

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pdo"); 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id_user, TIMEDIFF(lastacesso,agora) AS diferenca FROM users");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $sim_nao = ($row["diferenca"]  > 10) ? '0' : '1';
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET online='".$sim_nao."' where diferenca >= -00:25:18 "); 
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con); ?>

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Answer (score 0):

Veja que você está dando um `update` sem especificar um `id`, gerando assim uma alteração em todos os usuários.

Outra coisa, se você está fazendo uma `preparação` da query, por que não usar um `placeholder` na mesma?

No se `if`, Tente algo como:

```
if ($horaNovaFormatada  < $agora):
    $altera = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET online= ? WHERE id = ?");
    $altera->bindValue(array($sim_nao, $iddouser));
    $altera->execute();
    if($altera):
        echo "<script>window.location = 'online.php'</script>";
    else:
        echo "erro";
    endif;
```

Troque a variável `$iddouser` pelo  id do usuário.

Espero que que esteja gravando o `id` do usuário logado em algum local.

Comment: entendi , fiz com id e deu certo , mas queria poder varrer banco  e verifica todos os usuarios  quando tento fazer assim , todos os status mudam de uma vez só .

Comment: Usando o `id` do usuário logado,a alteração irá se aplicar a todos os usuários do sistema. Como você está identificando os usuários logados do seu sistema? Está gravando o id em algum lugar?